# Store Login Credentials inside CrystalReports?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

In My VB.NET Application and Crystal Reports(Version For VS2010)

Due to some reasons, I don't want to pass Login Credentials Runtime using Code. I want to store them design time in such a way that It never prompt for UserID, Password, Server... etc.

Also, It should not prompt for these credentials After I deploy My Application.

Please Provide some solution in this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: You wouldn't mind if someone would see these would you? If not I would highly recommend not storing sensitive data in any report like that.

Comment: Thank you. Security is not major issue in My case therefore...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save the password inside the report. The best approach in your case is to use Integrated Security and to handle the user permissions inside the database. In this case your security will be not compromised and there is no need of any code. If you don't want to do this then the only possible solution is to use an ODBC file and to edit it with notepad to add line like this:
PWD=YourPasswordHere

Keep in mind tat this will expose your password in plain text.

Comment: i dont want to use code in my application, just want that client cant open my database and only my crystal reports can access my database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do specify the database to the report while you are making it, so you just need to feed with the UserID and Password, I am not too sure how it works in VB but in Windows Forms and WPF we use this

```
private void ConfigureCrystalReports()
{
    rpt= new ReportDocument();
    rpt.Load(reportPath);
    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Database";
    connectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
    connectionInfo.Password="password";
    SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo,rpt);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
}
```

Something like this should work for you too.

Comment: doing this will not prompt the user!

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot save the password in the report, you can go into your ODBC connection and save your password on the connection itself.
This way, whenever you run any report that connects to that ODBC path, it will run without prompting for a password or username.